# Incorrect image selection using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, parse-platform

Using parse.com/Javascript and jquery.

Sorry if this is seen as too long a post, I'm still trying to understand the correct level of detail to provide...

I have two images that the user can click on. Once clicked the image is displayed in a pop up box and the user should be able to click the green send button and the image url is sent to the parse.com backend db.

At the moment though, no matter which image you click only the john_williams.jpg image is sent to parse.

I must be doing something fundamentally wrong for this to happen, like not storing the image variable correctly?

```
    <div class="shake shake-little"><img class ="go" src="http://kudosoo.com/Pics/John_Williams.jpg" alt="img"></div>
    <div class="shake shake-little"><img class ="go" src="http://kudosoo.com/Pics/Lisa_Wong.jpg" alt="img"></div>
```

Once clicked this creates a pop up, with the selected image displayed in the class "go" when the user clicks the green button, the selected image should be stored under the class "go" so it can later be retrieved in the below js and sent to the back end database.

```
        <!---Pop up box with info about the badge and options for user to complete-->           <div id="modal">
            <div id="heading">
                Award your friend this badge!?
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <div id="badgeselect">
                    <div class= "go"></div>
                </div>

                <a id="send" class="button green close"><img src="images/tick.png">Yes, do it now!</a>
                <a href="#" class="button red close"><img src="images/cross.png">No, Iâm insane!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

PARSE/JAVASCRIPT - MOVES THE IMAGE FROM THE WEBPAGE INTO THE POP UP BOX

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/jquery.reveal.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('.go').css('cursor', 'pointer');
            $('.go').click(function(e) { // Button which will activate our modal
                $(this).width(100).height(100).appendTo('#badgeselect');


                $('#modal').reveal({ // The item which will be opened with reveal
                    animation: 'fade',                   // fade, fadeAndPop, none
                    animationspeed: 600,                       // how fast animtions are
                    closeonbackgroundclick: true,              // if you click background will modal close?
                    dismissmodalclass: 'close'    // the class of a button or element that will close an open modal


                });
                return false;
               });
        });

            </script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
```

PARSE/JAVASCRIPT - SHOULD SEND THE SELECTED IMAGE TO PARSE.COM BACKEND

```
Parse.initialize("xxxx", "xxxx");
                    var badgeselected = $('.go').attr("src");
                    var MyBadges = Parse.Object.extend("myBadges");
                    var userbadges = new MyBadges();

                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        var badgeselected = $('.go').attr("src"); 
                        $("#send").click(function () {
                            userbadges.set("BadgeName", badgeselected);
                            console.log("done");

                            userbadges.save(null, {
                                success: function (results) {
                            // The object was saved successfully.
                            location.reload();
                        },
                        error: function (contact, error) {
                            // The save failed.
                            // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
                            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                        }
                    });
                        });
                    });
                </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your main problem is here:

```
var badgeselected = $('.go').attr("src");
```

This selects the "src" [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) of the first element which matches the selector. If there are multiples (which there should be at least 2), you'll always get the first.

Most likely you should add code to the `$('.go').click(function(e) {` function to capture the correct src there or possibly add an active class so that you can make a more selective selector in your `$("#send").click(function () {` function. I'm only speculating because I'm not certain what your application does.

Upon looking again, possibly just change your line to this:

```
var badgeselected = $('#badgeselect .go').attr("src");
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks - unfortunately that seems to be mean that BadgeName is being sent to parse.com as "undefined" If it helped, here is the link to the test area I'm working on with this http://kudosoo.com/JQUERYYTEST/dannyboy.html

Comment: You left out the space... on your sample page. In any case move `var badgeselected = $('#badgeselect .go').attr("src");` inside your `$("#send").click(function () {` function instead of before it.

Comment: Amended as suggested, sorry to be a pain but its still returning as undefined... ;-( kudosoo.com/JQUERYYTEST/dannyboy.html

Comment: Okay... next suggestion. Remove `<div class= "go"></div>`

Comment: YES! thank you so much! Would you mind explaining the conflict that caused to help me progress?

Comment: Okay... `$('#badgeselect .go')` selects all elements that are children of #badgeselect with a class of "go". Because you had that blank `<div class= "go"></div>` it was also being selected. Since `.attr` returns the value of the _first_ item selected, it was returning the "src" of that blank div. Which... is undefined. Clear enough?